# 16.04LTS 64bit sees only 3.5GB of memory out of 8GB

Tags: ram

I decided to move out of Windows 10 and I just finished with a clean install of Ubuntu 16.04LTS 64bit version - all updates to date .

Problem is that it sees only 3.5GB of RAM. I checked the BIOS, there are no options for the RAM memory and the BIOS as Windows 10, 30 minutes ago says that there are 8GB of memory installed.

Yes, I'm sure 100% the Ubuntu is 64bit version.

Anything I could try to fix this? I read a few things but nothing that will get me anywhere...

```
System information:
Toshiba Satellite-C655D
Processor : AMD E-300 APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics × 2 
Graphics : Gallium 0.4 on AMD PALM (DRM 2.43.0, LLVM 3.8.0) 
OS Type : 64-bit
SSD : 122.0 GB

Graphics : Gallium 0.4 on AMD PALM (DRM 2.43.0, LLVM 3.8.0)
```

Never saw anything like this in Windows. Over there graphic goes only by Radeon.

Thanks!

LE: At the suggestion of Pilot6, I come back with more information:

Output of free :

```
total used free shared buff/cache available 
Mem: 3548 1115 1181 35 1251 2142 
Swap: 3683 0 3683 .

    chip@chip-Satellite-C655D:~$ sudo dmidecode | awk '/Memory (Array|Device)/' RS=
[sudo] password for chip: 
Handle 0x0008, DMI type 16, 23 bytes
Physical Memory Array
    Location: System Board Or Motherboard
    Use: System Memory
    Error Correction Type: None
    Maximum Capacity: 8 GB
    Error Information Handle: No Error
    Number Of Devices: 2
Handle 0x0009, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0008
    Error Information Handle: 0x000A
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 8 bits
    Size: 4096 MB
    Form Factor: SODIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: DIMM0
    Bank Locator: BANK0
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 1066 MHz
    Manufacturer: Unknown
    Serial Number: 00000000
    Asset Tag: Unknown
    Part Number:                   
    Rank: 2
    Configured Clock Speed: 1066 MHz
Handle 0x000A, DMI type 18, 23 bytes
32-bit Memory Error Information
    Type: OK
    Granularity: Unknown
    Operation: Unknown
    Vendor Syndrome: Unknown
    Memory Array Address: Unknown
    Device Address: Unknown
    Resolution: Unknown
Handle 0x000C, DMI type 20, 35 bytes
Memory Device Mapped Address
    Starting Address: 0x00000000000
    Ending Address: 0x000FFFFFFFF
    Range Size: 4 GB
    Physical Device Handle: 0x0009
    Memory Array Mapped Address Handle: 0x0012
    Partition Row Position: 1
Handle 0x000D, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0008
    Error Information Handle: 0x000E
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 8 bits
    Size: 4096 MB
    Form Factor: SODIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: DIMM1
    Bank Locator: BANK0
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 1066 MHz
    Manufacturer: Unknown
    Serial Number: 00000000
    Asset Tag: Unknown
    Part Number:                   
    Rank: 2
    Configured Clock Speed: 1066 MHz
Handle 0x000E, DMI type 18, 23 bytes
32-bit Memory Error Information
    Type: OK
    Granularity: Unknown
    Operation: Unknown
    Vendor Syndrome: Unknown
    Memory Array Address: Unknown
    Device Address: Unknown
    Resolution: Unknown
Handle 0x0010, DMI type 20, 35 bytes
Memory Device Mapped Address
    Starting Address: 0x00100000000
    Ending Address: 0x001FFFFFFFF
    Range Size: 4 GB
    Physical Device Handle: 0x000D
    Memory Array Mapped Address Handle: 0x0012
    Partition Row Position: 1
Handle 0x0011, DMI type 18, 23 bytes
32-bit Memory Error Information
    Type: OK
    Granularity: Unknown
    Operation: Unknown
    Vendor Syndrome: Unknown
    Memory Array Address: Unknown
    Device Address: Unknown
    Resolution: Unknown
Handle 0x0012, DMI type 19, 31 bytes
Memory Array Mapped Address
    Starting Address: 0x00000000000
    Ending Address: 0x001FFFFFFFF
    Range Size: 8 GB
    Physical Array Handle: 0x0008
    Partition Width: 2
```

LLE: So I just swapped the memory so dimm 1 went to dimm 2 and vice-versa and now I got 7.5 GiB. Strange stuff... :D

```
chip@chip-Satellite-C655D:~$ free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7580         817        5983          21         779        6482
Swap:          3683           0        3683
```

Comment: Where do you see the 3.5 GB? Please add output of `free` to your question.

Comment: So, correct me if I'm wrong. To get "output of free" I went to terminal and wrote down "free -m" , this is the result: chip@chip-Satellite-C655D:~$ free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           3548        1115        1181          35        1251        2142
Swap:          3683           0        3683 .        I originally founded about the ram problem  from "About this computer" section from right upper corner of the desktop.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post output there. It is unreadable in comments.

Comment: And also please add output of `sudo dmidecode | awk '/Memory (Array|Device)/' RS=`

Comment: This is mysterious. There is really 8 GB of memory.

Comment: What does System Monitor say you have?

Comment: Maybe there was a bad conact or something like that.

Comment: It is strange, because I was using this PC so far and for sure I would have notice If I was running 4GB ram short.  The contacts and everything seems to be in place and free of dust or corrosion. Besides, I checked the BIOS and was saying 8GB RAM.    Anyhow, I'm glad it works and that I found you guys.  Being new in all of this I'm sure I'm going to be back here reading and asking questions in no time.  Thanks again :)